# change jquery chosen max_selected option dynamically

Tags: javascript, max, jquery-chosen, multiple-select

I've two select option, `class` and `class_attr`.

- `class` has 2 options: A and B
- `class_attr` has many options: aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ...

How do I implement if the user chooses A, the chosen `max_selected` is only 5 options, and if the user changes to B, the chosen `max_selected` is only 3 options.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```js
$(".class").change(function(){
    var code = $(this).val();
    if(code == 1){
        $(".class_attr").chosen({max_selected_options: 5});
    }
    else{
        $(".class_attr").chosen({max_selected_options: 3});         
    }
    $(".class_attr").trigger("liszt:updated");
});
```

But this seems to not work, the option list for `class_attr` will be set only once (the first class `max_selected_options` value selected, whether 5 or 3) and will never updated the `max_selected_options` after the first time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.class').chosen().change(function () {

    var code = $(this).val();
    var maxOptions = code == 1 ? 5 : 3;

    $(".class_attr").chosen('destroy').chosen({ max_selected_options: maxOptions });
});
```

It looks like you can't change any options after it's been initalised so it has to be destroyed before being created once more.

**[EDIT]** 
You can access Chosen instance through `$(".class_attr").data('chosen')`.
Then you can update options directly on the instance :

```
$('.class_attr').data('chosen').max_selected_options = 2;
$('.class_attr').trigger("chosen:updated");
```

Comment: Sorry2 I just got wrong type, I mean I trigger("liszt:updated"); on $(".class_attr") instead of $("#item_opt") but it still doesn't work

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply.
I've tried to implement your method, but it still can't work, and even the max_selected_options can't work at all.

Comment: Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/55FDq/) showing it working. I think you need to use chosen 1.0 to get the destroy functionality.

Answer (score 1):

In one my project I was need set maximun value not to all chosen drop-downs, so I used next initialization for them:

```
jQuery.each(jQuery(".chosen-select"), function (index, select) {
    var max_options = 0;//zero mean unlimited

    if (jQuery(select).data('max-options') !== 'undefined') {
        max_options = jQuery(select).data('max-options');
    }

    jQuery(select).chosen({
        search_contains: true,
        no_results_text: lang.no_results,
        placeholder_text_single: lang.select_one,
        placeholder_text_multiple: lang.select_some,
        disable_search: disable_search,
        max_selected_options: max_options
    });
});
```

On the drop-down which maximum selected options should be limited I set attribute data-max-options

**Example**:

```
<select class="chosen-select" data-max-options="5" name="lands[]" multiple="" data-placeholder=''>
                        //options in cycle here
</select>
```